# Update x509Certificate2 with correct Cryptographic Service Provider in Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, cryptography, x509certificate, bouncycastle, x509certificate2

I am creating `x509Certificate2` using `CertificateGenerator.GenerateCertificate` from this blog post of Wiktor Zychla (http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/12/how-to-create-x509certificate2.html)

[Bouncy Castle  crypto library](https://www.bouncycastle.org) is used to generate the certificate file. I need stronger signature algorithm to be used, so instead of `SHA1withRSA` (one in example) I am using `SHA256withRSA`.

Certificate is generated and exported successfully to `.pfx` file. When using the certificate later on I get error `Invalid algorithm specified`.

When  run `certutil -dump mycert.pfx`, I see incorrect Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP) is set: *Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0*

> ...
>
> ----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
>
> Provider = Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0
>
> ...

**How can I tell Bouncy Castle API to use different CSP?** The *Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider*, that actually can deal with `SHA256withRSA`.

There is very little resources on Bouncy Castle and `C#`, so any link to some documentation or related examples would be greatly appreciated.

List of CryptoAPI CSPs and algorithms, they support:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb931357(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to specify the CSP when you are importing the generated pfx. You can use this command

```
certutil -importPFX -csp "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -v c:\yourpfx.pfx AT_KEYEXCHANGE,NoExport,NoProtect
```

which will

- import into LocalMachine\My
- set CSP to Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider
- set private key usage to Exchange
- set private key as non-exportable
- set private key with no additional (password) protection

The CSP is windows specific field in PKCS#12 (PFX) and no one except windows is setting this. If you are using PFX from file `new X509Certificate2(filename)` then you have to change the private key. Convert `PrivateKey` property to `RSACryptoServiceProvider` and modify `CspParameters` (I don't have a snippet right now). Then set the modified `RSACryptoServiceProvider` back to `PrivateKey` property.

------- Edit

Here is the sample code that changes CSP on PFX read from file

```
// need to set exportable flag to be able to ... export private key
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"d:\test.pfx", "a", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var privKey = cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

// will be needed later
var exported = privKey.ToXmlString(true);

// change CSP
var cspParams = new CspParameters()
{
    ProviderType = 24,
    ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider"
};

// create new PrivateKey from CspParameters and exported privkey
var newPrivKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
newPrivKey.FromXmlString(exported);

// Assign edited private key back
cert.PrivateKey = newPrivKey;

// export as PKCS#12/PFX
var bytes = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "a");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have "wrong" certificates stored in DB. Don't do imports to LocalMachine (that's how our application works with certs). Need to regenerate those "wrong" certificates preferably in c# and store them back to DB, without breaking existing integrations. Is this even achievable in c#? :-)

Comment: Converted private key `var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider) x509cert.PrivateKey`. And there is `rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo`, which contains `ProviderType` and `ProviderName`. Those are readonly properties and cannot be changed, which makes sense for private key :-) Are those `CspParameters` you mentioned? and how to update them, if possible.

Comment: @mimo I've added sample code that should change the CSP.

Comment: Thanks for code. I am getting exception `CryptographicExceptio: Keyset does not exist` on last line: `cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "a")`. My cert.pfx  is in `c:\code\temp`. Have granted full access to AppPool under which is running my code to `temp` as well as to `cert.pfx`, but still getting `Keyset does not exist`.

Comment: @mimo That's weird. I did not try to run the code from web application. Every time I see this exception it has to do with privileges on the private key. You could try to play with `X509KeyStorageFlags` in the `X509Certificate2` constructor. Maybe it will help. I will try to look into this in the evening.

Comment: @mimo I have tried to put this code sample into a web application (MVC, .net 4.5.2) and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. Will try to look at the issue again on Sunday or Monday and get back.

Comment: made your code work without error (in console application). I read the .pfx file, do update and write `bytes` back to converted.pfx file. Now when run `certutil -dump converted.pfx`, got back `No key provider information Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption.`. However, I can install the new converted.pfx into Windows cert sotre, so it should not be corrupted. Need to look further into this.

Comment: @mimo I'm glad to hear (read) it. I hope you'll get it working. Good luck.

Comment: I've found out, that code for opening existing certificate and updating private key with security service provider works for me just on FIRST run. On all other runs I get "Keyset does not exists" exception on `cert.Export`. Got an idea, why? Thanks for your time and effort on this!

Comment: Also when I load the "converted" certificate  (on the first run), now in our real application, the property of `X509Certificate2 cert.PrivateKey` is `null`. Now when I import the "converted" certificate into windows Personal store and the export it as Private Key, I can use this "converted/exported" certificate in our application. However, the CSP is set to the wrong one, which brings me back at the beginning of the problem :-(

Answer (score 2):

You can set it when you export your pfx certificate using BouncyCastle.

It is pretty poorly documented, but the CSP can be set as a bag attribute when the pfx is created. To do this in BouncyCastle you need to know the Object Identifier of the CSP name field, which you can set as an attribute on the Pkcs12Store (for Microsoft CSP it's ["1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.1"](https://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.1)):

```
//Build your pem certificate as normal first
...
var certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(new Asn1SignatureFactory(SignatureAlgorithm, issuerPrivateKey, random));

//cert and key hashing algorithms can be set on the builder if required
var pkcs12Store = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder().Build();
var certificateEntry = new X509CertificateEntry(certificate);

var microsoftCspNameObjectIdentifier = new DerObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.1");

pkcs12Store.SetKeyEntry(certificate.SubjectDN + "_key", new AsymmetricKeyEntry(subjectPrivateKey, new Dictionary<DerObjectIdentifier, Asn1Encodable> { { microsoftCspNameObjectIdentifier, new DerBmpString("Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider") } }), new[] { certificateEntry });

//Save your pkcs12 to a stream (file stream to save to file/memory stream if you want bytes etc)
pkcs12Store.Save(...);
```