# System.Security.AccessControl.PrivilegeNotHeldException

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, authorization, .net-framework-version

I am facing a problem while signing the data with the help of a private key. I can't get the required data in the private certificate; I think I am not able to get proper privilege or permission.

```
((System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider)privateCertificate.PrivateKey).CspKeyContainerInfo.CryptoKeySecurity = ((System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider)privateCertificate.PrivateKey).CspKeyContainerInfo.CryptoKeySecurity
   threw an exception of type 'System.Security.AccessControl.PrivilegeNotHeldException'
```

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Load the public key from the .cer file
            X509Certificate2 publicCertificate = new X509Certificate2("public.cer");
            RSAParameters publicKey = ((RSA)publicCertificate.PublicKey.Key).ExportParameters(false);

            // Load the private key from the .pfx file
            X509Certificate2 privateCertificate = new X509Certificate2("private.pfx", "marwadi", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)privateCertificate.PrivateKey;

            // Message to be encrypted
            string originalMessage = "Vivek";

            // Convert the message to bytes
            byte[] originalBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalMessage);

            // Encrypt the message using the public key
            byte[] encryptedBytes = Encryption(originalBytes, publicKey, true);

            // Generate a signature for the encrypted data
            byte[] signature = GenerateSignature(encryptedBytes, privateKey);

            // Verify the signature before decryption
            if (VerifySignature(encryptedBytes, signature, publicKey))
            {
                // Decrypt the message using the private key
                byte[] decryptedData = Decryption(encryptedBytes, privateKey);

                // Convert the decrypted bytes back to a string
                string decryptedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);

                // Display the results
                Console.WriteLine("Original Message: " + originalMessage);
                Console.WriteLine("Encrypted Message: " + Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes));
                Console.WriteLine("Signature: " + Convert.ToBase64String(signature));
                Console.WriteLine("Decrypted Message: " + decryptedMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Signature. Aborting decryption.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + e.StackTrace);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static public byte[] Encryption(byte[] data, RSAParameters publicKey, bool doOAEPPadding)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] encryptedData;
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rsa.ImportParameters(publicKey);
                encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(data, doOAEPPadding);
            }
            return encryptedData;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Encryption error: " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + e.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }
    }

    static public byte[] GenerateSignature(byte[] data, RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey)
    {
        try
        {
            RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter rsaFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(privateKey);
            rsaFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm(nameof(SHA256));
            return rsaFormatter.CreateSignature(data);
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Signature generation error: " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + e.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }
    }

    static public bool VerifySignature(byte[] data, byte[] signature, RSAParameters publicKey)
    {
        try
        {
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rsa.ImportParameters(publicKey);
                RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter rsaDeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(rsa);
                rsaDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm(nameof(SHA256));
                return rsaDeformatter.VerifySignature(data, signature);
            }
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Signature verification error: " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + e.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
    }

    static public byte[] Decryption(byte[] data, RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey)
    {
        try
        {
            return privateKey.Decrypt(data, true);
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Decryption error: " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + e.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should specify the .NET version in the question and not in the comment (especially if you are using a version as old as 4.5). However, I cannot reproduce the problem even with .NET Framework 4.5. It is probably, as you suspect, a permission problem that is difficult to reproduce without further information.

Comment: But there is at least one more bug: `RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter#CreateSignature()` does not hash implicitly, i.e. you have to hash the data *explicitly* (as in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsapkcs1signatureformatter?view=netframework-4.5#examples)) in order to be compliant with the RSA signature standard (note that the hash used must correspond to the hash specified with `SetHashAlgorithm()`).

Comment: Another issue (possibly only in my environment) is that the CSP of the exported private key does not support SHA256 (only SHA1). In this case the CSP has to be replaced (e.g. with the *Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider*). For me, it was successful to import the key into a new `RSACryptoServiceProvider` intance (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45085923/9014097) with `CspParameters`).

Comment: Thank you @Topaco for your suggestions and i have tried it but still i am facing same issue so i think there is an issue in permission to privateKey so i will try to go through that permissions .

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Load the public key from the .cer file
            X509Certificate2 publicCertificate = new X509Certificate2("Your public cer");
    RSA publicRSA = publicCertificate.GetRSAPublicKey(); // Using GetRSAPublicKey for better compatibility

            // Load the private key from the .pfx file
            X509Certificate2 privateCertificate = new X509Certificate2("Your private pfx", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
            RSA privateRSA = privateCertificate.GetRSAPrivateKey(); // Using GetRSAPrivateKey for better compatibility

            // Message to be encrypted
            string originalMessage = "Vivek";
            byte[] originalBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalMessage);

            // Encrypt the message using the public key
            byte[] encryptedBytes = EncryptData(originalBytes, publicRSA);

            // Generate a signature for the encrypted data
            byte[] signature = GenerateSignature(encryptedBytes, privateRSA);

            // Verify the signature before decryption
            if (VerifySignature(encryptedBytes, signature, publicRSA))
            {
                // Decrypt the message using the private key
                byte[] decryptedData = DecryptData(encryptedBytes, privateRSA);

                // Convert the decrypted bytes back to a string
                string decryptedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);

                // Display the results
                Console.WriteLine("Original Message: " + originalMessage);
                Console.WriteLine("Encrypted Message: " + Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes));
                Console.WriteLine("Signature: " + Convert.ToBase64String(signature));
                Console.WriteLine("Decrypted Message: " + decryptedMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Signature. Aborting decryption.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static byte[] EncryptData(byte[] data, RSA publicKey)
    {
        return publicKey.Encrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
    }

    static byte[] DecryptData(byte[] data, RSA privateKey)
    {
        return privateKey.Decrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
    }

    static byte[] GenerateSignature(byte[] data, RSA privateKey)
    {
        return privateKey.SignData(data, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    }

    static bool VerifySignature(byte[] data, byte[] signature, RSA publicKey)
    {
        return publicKey.VerifyData(data, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    }
}


This code will solve the issue as it uses getter for both public and private RSA if you face any other error feel free to post it
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer jatan but i think you may be using new version of .net framework. As of now i am using framework version 4.5 and getter for both private and public key is not available in this version

Comment: Code with no explanation is much less useful to future visitors than code with a good explanation in prose. Code-only answers are discouraged for this reason.